# Plot doesn't reset at the end of animation with matplotlib.animation

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, animation

I'm using matplotlib.animation to create a 4 bar linkage. in the arrX# arrY# variables I have the x&y of the lines (360 values in each). I'm using the standard template from the matplotlib website. 
During one loop where variable frame goes from 0 to 359 everything is fine. But when it goes for a second loop, the image at the end (frame=359) of the last loop stays on the plot. At the end of every next plot it is drawn again and again.

How can I reset the plot or what can I do to eliminate the old lines at the end of the loop?

Code is below.
Image shows two sets of lines, where one set of lines is static that doesn't go away and is redrawn again and again at the end of each loop.

```
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ln1, = plt.plot([], [], '-r')
ln2, = plt.plot([], [], '-b')
ln3, = plt.plot([], [], '-g')

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(-100, 300)
    ax.set_ylim(-100, 200)
    return ln1,ln2,ln3

def update(frame):
    xdata=(arrX2[frame])
    ydata=(arrY2[frame])
    ln1.set_data([0,xdata], [0,ydata])
    ln2.set_data([xdata,arrX3[frame]],[ydata,arrY3[frame]])
    ln3.set_data([d,arrX3[frame]],[0,arrY3[frame]])
    return ln1,ln2,ln3

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=range(0,360,1), init_func=init, blit=True,interval=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: When I get rid of **init** function it works. But why? Here is what I did:
I took these two lines from init and put it outside of it. This way I still have a chance to define the plot.:
    **ax.set_xlim(-100, 300);    
    ax.set_ylim(-100, 200)**
Then in **FuncAnimation** deleted the **init_func=init**
But I don't understand why it works this way now.

Comment: I cannot seem to reproduce your problem. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. that also includes made up data so the problem can be investigated

Comment: I would try to include `lnXXXX.set_data([], [])` in your `init()` function for starter

Comment: @DizietAsahi, yeah, I've tried it. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was creating a "Verifiable example" i found the problem.
Originally my **init()** function was this:

```
def init():
ax.set_xlim(-100, 300)
ax.set_ylim(-100, 200)
return ln1,ln2,ln3
```

This is wrong. This function should only hold the empty objects so that the animator can look into here and see what objects will need to be updated on each frame in the **update()** function.

Otherwise, in my example, once the "video reel" came to an end, and the time for the re-initialization came up, it simply plotted the last known line objects.

In the **init()** function I only kept the empty line objects. This worked.

```
def init():
ln1, = plt.plot([], [], '-r')
ln2, = plt.plot([], [], '-b')
ln3, = plt.plot([], [], '-g')
return ln1,ln2,ln3,
```

I'm convinced that this was an error. If not I just don't know.

P.S. Not sure if this needs to be kept here or not since this was a syntax error. I leave it up to more experienced users to decide :)